# Integrate schema metatdata during XML Parsing with Xerces C++

Tags: c++, xml, xml-parsing, xerces, xerces-c

I want to parse an XML file and look up the datatype of attributes and entities in an XML schema file (.xsd) when I traverse the DOM.

I found out that I can use the post schema validation infoset (PSVI) to get that information. For this I should be able to get a nodes info by the getFeature method:

```
info = (xercesc::DOMPSVITypeInfo*) domNode->getFeature(xercesc::XMLUni::fgXercesDOMHasPSVIInfo, xercesc::XMLUni::fgVersion1_1);
```

However I first seem to have to enable this feature. As there is no setFeature method in the parser object I tried "useImplementation", but this just crashes my program.

As the documentation of Xerces is pretty sparse in respect to PSVI, maybe someone here knows how to get schema information while parsing an XML document using a XercesDOMParser.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://xerces.apache.org/xerces2-j/faq-xs.html

Comment: @user2642282 thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately this FAQ is for Java and there are some differences in the API compared to C++. Also it doesn't say *how* to set a property to get a PSVIDocumentImpl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution meanwhile:

```
//create parser
static const XMLCh gLS[] = { xercesc::chLatin_L, xercesc::chLatin_S, xercesc::chNull };
xercesc::DOMImplementation *impl = xercesc::DOMImplementationRegistry::getDOMImplementation(gLS);
DOMLSParserImpl* parser = dynamic_cast<DOMLSParserImpl*>(impl->createLSParser(DOMImplementationLS::MODE_SYNCHRONOUS, 0));

//configure
parser->setParameter(xercesc::XMLUni::fgXercesDOMHasPSVIInfo, true);  //collect schema info
parser->setParameter(xercesc::XMLUni::fgDOMComments, false); //discard comments
parser->setExternalNoNamespaceSchemaLocation("schema.xsd");
parser->setDoSchema(true);
parser->setDoNamespaces(true);
parser->setValidationScheme(xercesc::XercesDOMParser::Val_Always);

parser->parseURI("file.xml");

...

xercesc::DOMAttr& attr = (xercesc::DOMAttr&) attributeNode;
cout << " name: " << transcode(attr.getName()) << " type: " << transcode(attr.getSchemaTypeInfo()->getTypeName()) << ", ";
```

It's a bit messy to cast the the parser down to the Impl class, but it's the only way I found to access the setParameter function. I think there must be a "correct" way to initialize the parser, though...

Also it's important to set the validation scheme and set DoSchema to true, otherwise the parser won't attach the schema information the the DOM elements.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to configure the [DOMLSParser](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/apiDocs-3/classDOMLSParser.html) through its [DOMConfiguration](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/apiDocs-3/classDOMConfiguration.html), (see the `getDomConfig()` function) and avoid the cast to the implementation class. The `DOMConfiguration` has a couple `setParameter()` functions which should support Xerces' many configuration properties, including those for XML Schema validation.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the hint! The DOMConfiguration indeed exposes these parameters, but if I set them through it, I don't get the schema infos. No idea why though.

Comment: Not sure which version of Xerces-C you're using but there should be a parameter corresponding to each of the direct calls you were making on DOMLSParserImpl.

Comment: Mappings, pulled from the current version of DOMLSParserImpl.cpp in Apache's SVN repository: setExternalNoNamespaceSchemaLocation() --> XMLUni::fgXercesSchemaExternalNoNameSpaceSchemaLocation, 
setDoSchema() --> XMLUni::fgXercesSchema,
setDoNamespaces() --> XMLUni::fgDOMNamespaces,
setValidationScheme() --> XMLUni::fgDOMValidate