# Filter XML elements of type anyURI using XSD

Tags: xml, go, xsd, libxml2

I am using [go-libxml2](https://github.com/lestrrat/go-libxml2). I have an XSD and also a XML. I want to filter all anyURI elements in the XML based on XSD including nested elements. Because I am trying to update all anyURI elements in a XML by adding a queryparam. For example

XSD:

```
    <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xs:element name="grandParent">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="AnyURI1" type="xs:anyURI" 
         maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:element name="parent">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="AnyURI2" type="xs:anyURI" 
           maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:element name="children">
      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element name="AnyURI3" type="xs:anyURI" 
             maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
  </xs:element>
</xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

XML

```
    <grandParent>
  <AnyURI1>    http://uri_gp1.com </AnyURI1>
  <AnyURI1>    http://uri_gp2.com </AnyURI1>
  <parent>
    <AnyURI2>    http://uri_p1.com    </AnyURI2>
    <AnyURI2>    http://uri_p2.com    </AnyURI2>
    <children>
      <AnyURI3>    http://uri_child1.com    </AnyURI3>
      <AnyURI3>    http://uri_child2.com    </AnyURI3>
    </children>
  </parent>
</grandParent>
```

In the above XML, I want to filter and update all element of type "anyURI" like `<AnyURI1>, <AnyURI2> and <anyURI3>`

How can I achieve this using golang?

Answer (score 3):

I think you should consider alternative choices of technology for this. The problem becomes very easy with a schema-aware XSLT transformation:

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="3.0"
               xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy">
  <xsl:template match="element(*, xs:anyURI)/text()">
    <xsl:value-of select=". || '?param=value'"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Its a good idea. But I don't see any good libraries to implement this in golang. I am still waiting for some more comments.

Answer (score 0):

For fully featured XML processors supporting XML Schema, the Post Schema Validation Infoset (PSVI) would provide you exactly what you want. A [PSVI Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34878419/integrate-schema-metatdata-during-xml-parsing-with-xerces-c/) shows how to access it using Xerces C.

From what I can see, the problem with go-libxml2 is that libxml2 itself did not get to implement PSVI. The designers allowed for a "future" PSVI extension which I don't think ever materialized. (Have a look at [libxml2 doc](http://www.xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-tree.html) and search for PSVI.) Because of this, the answer is you can't achieve what you want.

If you're willing to integrate with other platforms, Java xerces would work in that you could delegate the task to it.